# Limit django for loop in the template or the view for better performance?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a for loop on my template. I only want to display the first 3 items in the loop for a blog.

At present there are only 20 blog entries, but if the blog entries are say 500 or more, from a performance perspective, is it better to limit the loop in the views.py code or in the template code?

Here is the loop limit in the views.py file:

```
blog_latest_entries = BlogDetails.objects.filter(blog_date_published__lte=date_now).order_by('-blog_date_published')[:3]
.....
return render(request, 'page.html', {
    'blog': blog_details_latest_entries,
```

Here is the limit in the template code:

```
{% for blog in blog|slice:"3" %}
```

Which option is best for performance. I suspect the views.py approach, but I would like my suspicion backed up by someone with real knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: As I saw up to now, `slice` is the best method in order to limit list elements.

Comment: The same. Use Django Debug Toolbar, Luke!

Comment: Limit the qs in the view. The SQL statement will be executed in both cases but the limited SQL statement is faster and not so heavy. Cutting the qs in the template will have the same output but the way to get there takes longer since you load all the data even when you just need the first three elements.
If you want to do more optimization I suggest to look up `prefetch_related()` and `values_list()`.
And please rename the running variable in your `for loop`. it shouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as @hansTheFranz said Django querysets are lazy. That means a query will hit the database only when you ask for it.

So until your template ask for the result, it wont execute the query. So, yes you can use:

```
blog_latest_entries = BlogDetails.objects.filter(blog_date_published__lte=date_now).order_by('-blog_date_published')
{% for new in news|slice:":10" %}
```

is the same than use `SELECT * FROM Customers LIMIT 3;`